# How do I use Ubuntu One beta in Windows

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows-7

In Ubuntu, my Ubuntu One account shows up in the file manager as a place like any other accessible directory. How do I get it to show up in Windows 7 the same way using the Ubuntu One beta? Do I need to map it in Windows Explorer as a network drive, or... ?

A pointer to the right How-To or manual would be fine. I don't mind rreading the manual if I can find it.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow this howto https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/Windows and you should see your synchronised files in *My Documents\Ubuntu One*

Comment: fluteflute was right - I missed the How-to and so asked here. Thank you, Vojtech, it was exactly what I was looking for. And I have to say - the way it works is quite elegant.